# How to find and replace text over multiple lines in Linux?

Tags: xml, linux, bash, text, replace

I am reading from an XML file and want to find this property and replace the value 50 by 45
Before:

```
<name>ipc.client.connect.max.retries</name> 
<value>50</value>
```

After:

```
<name>ipc.client.connect.max.retries</name> 
<value>45</value>
```

I am using

```
pcregrep -M '<name>ipc.client.connect.max.retries</name>.*(\n|.)*<value>45</value>' core-site.xml
```

to find the string.

I tried

```
sed 's/$string1/$string2' core-site.xml
```

it doesnt work

Comment: Can you post the `core-site.xml` sample file?

Comment: It's been said and written many times in the past: Do not use regex to parse XML!

Comment: <configuration>

    <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://c6401.ambari.apache.org:8020</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
      <value>360</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>ha.failover-controller.active-standby-elector.zk.op.retries</name>
      <value>120</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hadoop.http.authentication.simple.anonymous.allowed</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.groups</name>

Comment: @VivekRathod: You have to place that code in the question (where it can be properly formatted and read without reading the comments), not in a  comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with:

```
sed '/<name>/{N;s/50/45/}' yourfilename
```

To find the tag `<name>` and then on the following line replace `50` with `45`. To edit in place use `sed -i`, or for a backup of the original `sed -i.bak`